# Is it possible to detect when a command uses no count?

Tags: count

Based on v:count help I define:

```
:map _x :<C-U>echo "the count is " . v:count . ' and count1 is ' . v:count1<CR>
```

So

```
_x
the count is 0 and count1 is 1
0_x
the count is 0 and count1 is 1
1_x
the count is 1 and count1 is 1
3_x
the count is 3 and count1 is 3
```

My goal is detect when map do not get count at all, but v:count always get a 0 value.

Is there any chance to detect that?

Comment: It might be better at this stage to create a separate, new question asking specifically about the counts passed to user-defined ex commands. The existing answer is correct for the original question you asked (which gave the example of a normal-mode map), and some might consider it unsporting to change the parameters at this point. (Not meaning to imply that you did anything wrong originally: I understand it's not necessarily obvious that normal-mode and command-line mode `count`s would behave differently.)

Comment: I create a wrong use case then http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html (Search for special case). Let's accept the answer

Comment: Accepting the answer looks good to me! (In case it's not clear, that bit of the documentation is explaining how you can do something like `nnoremap 0 dd` but then still use a normal-mode command with a count such as `20j` without triggering your mapping when you type the `0` in `20`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0` is not a valid count.  `0_x` does not mean give a count of `0` to command `_x`, it means go to the first column of the line, then run command `_x`.  You cannot give `0` as a count.

Hence, `v:count == 0` means no count is provided.  Some commands interpret count `0` as equivalent to `1`.  For this reason, a shortcut `v:count1` is also provided which is the same as `v:count` except when no count is given, in which case `v:count == 1`. You cannot use `v:count1` alone to determine when no count is provided.

Comment: It defaults to `-count=0` because `0` is used as the "no count provided" value. Normal mode commands can never receive a count of `0`.

Comment: @albfan I think there is some confusion between ex commands like `:Search` and normal mode commands like `_x`.  They both have something called a "count" but they are not the same thing at all.